# COM class factory Error in WCF Service

Tags: .net, informix

I have a problem with COM object: I have a service which connect to database. 
All connection's information service read from connection.config file.
But I have a error when service trying to connect to database:

translate of my error:

> Failure to obtain a class factory for component with COM CLSID
>   {6EB22881-8A19-11D0-81B6-00A0C9231C29}  as a result of the following
>   error: 80070005.

Comment: Some ideas for troubleshooting this error code: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/code/code_80070005.htm

Comment: It is a Windows error, "access denied".  The CLSID is associated with MTS.  There's such a thing as having *too many* privileges I suppose, run the service with a restricted user account that you know can access the dbase.